# Two instances of a class can call method (Synchronized on some object) parallelly

Tags: java

I have a method like :

```
public void processChildNodes(Node result, Node source) {
    synchronized (source) {
        NodeList nodes = source.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
          processNode(result, nodes.item(i));
        }
    }
  }
```

Now let say I am trying to call processChildNodes with two different instances of the class in which this method is present with same source (second parameter of method), Is it possible that those 2 execution can go parallely??

Comment: Why is this any different from synchronizing on a single object ? Since 'source' refers to the same object in both calls, it will be the same behavior as synchronizing on a single object. Why the confusion ?

Answer (score 2):

No, the method will be called but the content within the synchronized block will not be executed parallely  . This is because as you have mentioned you are using the same source object. since the lock is acquired on the object the synchronization will work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to take an object lock. If you pass the same object then your processing will be synchronized, which means one thread will executing the code inside the syncronized block and the other thread will be waiting for it. But if you are passing two different objects then  the they will use two different locks, which means they are not dependent on each other to take the lock. So both of them will execute in parallel.

As you have written the code and trying to synchronize the execution using source object. So make sure that both of your threads are using same source object to get the desired result.

Comment: Hmm I agree with you but based on the behavior what I am seeing it seems synchronized block is being executed parallel on calling method using two different object of class with same source object.

Comment: Can you share the code of creation of node object and also the code which is calling processChildNodes.

Comment: Yes sure I will share in some time

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the source object to synchronize the synchronization should work properly. If the objects used in the two instances are different the two executions may happen in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Java is pass-by-value, meaning that the `Node` passed is actually a copy. The system makes two separate copies for the two separate calls to the method, meaning that the two will execute in parallel. Note that this also means your synchronized block may be ineffective. Be careful of data races.</s>

**EDIT**

I did a little more research and found [this page](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html) that describes how the parameters work. Given this new information, I think that my answer is invalid, but I'm still not 100% sure.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Java will pass a copy of a pointer to the Node. So the value of Node is shared, not a copy. And hence you will synchronize on the same object.

Comment: Bravo, you have the courage to admit mistakes.. [at least as long as you stay anonymous...]

Comment: Yes, my initial answer was based on intuition. This is a tricky problem, though. I'm going to have to write some tests to figure this one out for experience.

Comment: If you know C, think of a java reference as a C pointer. When you call a function `f(obj);` the function `f` is receiving the value of the pointer (java reference) to the object. The object itself is not copied.